# head rendering in body laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I'm tasked to correct this from an outside developer, but am stumped.
I reviewed two very similar Stackoverflow questions, from 6 years ago,
but could not resolve this.

The following is roughly how it renders in a browser:

```
<HTML lang="en">
<head>(this is completely empty)</head>
<body >
<nav></nav>
<div class="header-nav">
</div>
links display
```

Finally, the 'head' section from the code below, renders here
(meta tags, title etc.) but without the 'head' tags.

Frontapp.blade.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    
        <title>Some website</title>
    
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link href="{{ asset('argon') }}/img/brand/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">
    
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Extra details for Live View on GitHub Pages aaaddd -->
    
        <!-- Icons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
        {{-- <link href="{{ asset('argon') }}/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
        {{-- <link href="{{ asset('argon') }}/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
    
        {{-- Animation link --}}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
    
        {{-- Bootstrap --}}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <!-- Argon CSS -->
        {{-- <link type="text/css" href="{{ asset('argon') }}/css/argon.css?v=1.0.0" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
        <link type="text/css" href="{{ asset('argon') }}/css/web.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    
    
    <body class="{{ $class ?? '' }}">
        {{-- @auth()
                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                @csrf
                </form>
                @include('layouts.navbars.sidebar')
        @endauth --}}
    
        {{-- <div class="main-content">
                @include('layouts.navbars.navbar')
                @yield('content')
            </div> --}}
    
        {{-- @guest()
                @include('layouts.footers.guest')
            @endguest --}}
    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    
        @stack('js')
        <script>
            setTimeout(() => {
            let allAlerts = document.querySelectorAll(".alert");
            allAlerts.forEach((alert) => {
                alert.remove();
            });
        }, 6000);
        </script>
    
        {{-- <script>
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getFullYear();
            document.querySelector(".year").innerText = n;
        </script> --}}
    
        <!-- Argon JS abcd-->
        {{-- <script src="{{ asset('argon') }}/js/argon.js?v=1.0.0"></script> --}}
        <script src="{{ asset('argon') }}/js/custom.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('argon') }}/js/animation.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Edit, I was requested to provide the controller for FrontApp.Blade.php
I'm not completely certain what to put here but here's what I found.
home.blade.php   (first 16 lines)**

```
@extends('layouts.frontapp')
@include('layouts.frontlayout.header')

<div class="jumbotron homeBanner">
    <h1>Somewebsite</h1>
    <h4 class="lead">text</h4>
    <h4 class="lead">text</h4>
    <br>
    <a class="btn btn-lg banner-button" href="#" role="button">EXPLORE MORE <i class="las la-arrow-right text-white"></i></a>
    </p>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a class="ct-btn-scroll circle-down-arrow-icon" href="#first-section"><i class="las la-chevron-circle-down"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Header.blade.php   (first 25 lines)**

```
@extends('layouts.frontapp')
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-faded navbar-light shadow-sm">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #666 !important"><i class="las la-phone-volume"></i> phone</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="mailto:info@Somewebsite.com"
                target="_blank"  style="color: #666 !important"><i class="las la-envelope"></i> info@Somewebsite.com</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav rightNav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="lab la-facebook-f"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="lab la-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="lab la-instagram"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Here is how the full page renders, the head from the Blade is in the wrong position. Putting the head at line 73 to line 132 in the html**

````
<html lang="en"><head></head><body class="" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="8.878.0" data-gr-ext-installed=""><nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-faded navbar-light shadow-sm">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #666 !important"><i class="las la-phone-volume"></i> phone</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="mailto:info@somewebsite.com" target="_blank" style="color: #666 !important"><i class="las la-envelope"></i> info@somewebsite.com</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav rightNav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="lab la-facebook-f"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="lab la-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="lab la-instagram"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="header-nav">
    <div class="sticky-top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbarcolor">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <a href="/">
                        <img src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/img/websiteImages/Somewebsite-new-logo.png" alt="Logo" id="navIcon">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    
                    <i class="las la-bars text-white"></i>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav rightNav my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link webnav" id="home-nav" href="/">HOME</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link webnav" id="about-us-nav" href="/about">ABOUT US</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link webnav" id="electrical-nav" href="/electrical">ELECTRICAL</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link webnav" id="stab-nav" href="/stabalizers">STAB</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link webnav" id="partners-nav" href="/partners">PARTNERSHIP</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link webnav" id="blog-nav" href="/blog">BLOG</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link webnav" id="contact-nav" href="/contact">CONTACT</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </nav>
    </div>
</div>





    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="y8br0kSwVHC1QSvZqPdxaw3MyykzAKlTa80MvaS8">
    <title>Somewebsite</title>
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link href="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/img/brand/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Extra details for Live View on GitHub Pages aaaddd -->
    <!-- Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
    
    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Argon CSS -->
    
    <link type="text/css" href="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/css/web.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
        <script>
        setTimeout(() => {
        let allAlerts = document.querySelectorAll(".alert");
        allAlerts.forEach((alert) => {
            alert.remove();
        });
    }, 6000);
    </script>
    
    <!-- Argon JS abcd-->
    
    <script src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/js/animation.js"></script>




<div class="jumbotron homeBanner">
    <h1>Somewebsite</h1>
    <h4 class="lead">text</h4>
    <h4 class="lead">Services</h4>
    <br>
    <a class="btn btn-lg banner-button" href="#" role="button">EXPLORE MORE <i class="las la-arrow-right text-white"></i></a>
    <p></p>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a class="ct-btn-scroll circle-down-arrow-icon" href="#first-section"><i class="las la-chevron-circle-down"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="first-section" class="pt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row pt-5">
            <div class="col-md-6 p-5">
                <h4 class="animated-left animate__animated">Engineering</h4>
                <br>
                <p class="animated-left animate__animated">
                    Text 
                </p>    
                <p class="animated-left animate__animated"> 
                    Text
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <img class="animated-fadein animate__animated" src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/img/websiteImages/home_first_para.jpg" alt="home_image-01" id="home_image-01">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row pt-5">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <img class="animated-fadein animate__animated animate__delay-1s" src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/img/websiteImages/home_second_para.png" alt="home_image-02" id="home_image-02">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 p-5">
                <h4 class="animated-right animate__animated animate__delay-1s">Engineering</h4>
                <br>
                <p class="animated-right animate__animated animate__delay-1s">
                   Text
                </p>
                <p class="animated-right animate__animated animate__delay-1s">
                    Text

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<section id="second-section" class="pt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 business-solutions-col text-center p-5">
            <h3>business solutions</h3>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/img/websiteImages/Complete-Care.png" id="img-complete-care">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <p class="text-justify animated-down animate__animated animate__delay-1s"><span id="complete-care">Complete Care</span><br>
                        Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/img/websiteImages/Electrical-Solutions.png" id="img-electrical-solutions">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <p class="text-justify animated-down animate__animated animate__delay-1s"><span id="electrical-solutions">Electrical</span><br>
                        Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/img/websiteImages/Stab.png" id="img-stab">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <p class="text-justify animated-down animate__animated animate__delay-1s"><span id="stab">Stab</span><br>
                        Our sister company, 
                         <a class="btn btn-sm product-button" href="https://www.SisterWebsite.com" role="button">Please visit SisterWebsite.com</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 business-solutions-video animated-zoomin animate__animated animate__delay-1s">
            <div id="video-col" style="margin-right: 0%;margin-left: -3%;" hidden="">
                
                    <video class="bs-video" id="bs-video" controls="">
                        <source src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/img/websiteImages/New_3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
            </div>
        </div>
        
                    </div>
                
            
        
    
</section>
<section id="third-section">
    <div class="third-sec-with-img">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="animated-right animate__animated animate__delay-3s">ENGINEERING</h3>
            <p class="lead animated-right animate__animated animate__delay-3s">Engineering</p>
            <p class="animated-right animate__animated animate__delay-3s">
                text removed
             
</p>
            <a class="btn btn-outline btn-lg btnoutline-white animated-right animate__animated animate__delay-3s" href="https://www.somewebsite.com/electrical" role="button">Electrical| <i class="las la-arrow-right text-white"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a class="btn btn-outline btn-lg btnoutline-white animated-right animate__animated animate__delay-3s" href="#" role="button">Service Request Form | <i class="las la-arrow-right text-white"></i></a>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="third-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 pb-5 text-right" id="abc-d-img">
                <img src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/img/websiteImages/sister_new.png" alt="sister">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 pt-5 pb-5 text-left sister-colum">
                <h6 style="color: #890304;">sister</h6>
                <p>Excellence </p>
                <h4>Products</h4>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <a class="btn btn-sm product-button" href="https://www.somewebsite.com/stab" role="button">PRODUCT <i class="las la-arrow-right text-white"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<footer class="bg-white text-center text-lg-start footerMain">
    <div class="border-top-2" id="main-footer">
        <div class="container p-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="/">
                        <img src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/img/websiteImages/somewebsite-new-logo.png" alt="Logo" id="footer-logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3 id="footer-address">ADDRESS</h3>
                    <p>
                        text
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="footer-icon">
                    <i class="lab la-facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com//" target="_blank"> </a></i>
                    <i class="lab la-twitter"></i>
                    <i class="lab la-linkedin"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center p-3 second-footer">
        somewebsite <span class="year">2021</span> | All Rights Reserved <strong>
        
        
    </strong></div><strong>
</strong></footer><strong>





    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="y8br0kSwVHC1QSvZqPdxaw3MyykzAKlTa80MvaS8">

    <title>Some Webstite</title>

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link href="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/img/brand/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Extra details for Live View on GitHub Pages aaaddd -->

    <!-- Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
    
    

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Argon CSS -->
    
    <link type="text/css" href="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/css/web.css" rel="stylesheet">





    

    

    

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

        <script>
        setTimeout(() => {
        let allAlerts = document.querySelectorAll(".alert");
        allAlerts.forEach((alert) => {
            alert.remove();
        });
    }, 6000);
    </script>

    

    <!-- Argon JS abcd-->
    
    <script src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/js/animation.js"></script>








    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="y8br0kSwVHC1QSvZqPdxaw3MyykzAKlTa80MvaS8">

    <title>SomeWebsite</title>

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link href="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/img/brand/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Extra details for Live View on GitHub Pages aaaddd -->

    <!-- Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
    
    

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Argon CSS -->
    
    <link type="text/css" href="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/css/web.css" rel="stylesheet">





    

    

    

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

        <script>
        setTimeout(() => {
        let allAlerts = document.querySelectorAll(".alert");
        allAlerts.forEach((alert) => {
            alert.remove();
        });
    }, 6000);
    </script>

    

    <!-- Argon JS abcd-->
    
    <script src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.somewebsite.com/argon/js/animation.js"></script>



</strong></body></html>



```
````

Comment: Show us your controller please, as you are saying it is displaying X inside your `body` tag but in your blade you have more content than what you are showing...

Comment: Added the controller code requested by matiaslauriti

Comment: I still need assistance